# Using a container with a flask app running boto3 to read from LocalStack S3 container

Tags: python, docker, flask, boto3, localstack

I have several containers all running on the same bridge network:

- Postgres on port 5432
- LocalStack mock S3 on port 4566
- Flask app on port 5000

The Flask app has two endpoints, which are both only a couple of lines of code (see below) and are calling functions I've written which work when run locally. The first is reading json data from a table hosted by the Postgres container using the psycopg2 package and this is working correctly. The second is trying to read a json file from the LocalStack S3 bucket using the boto3 package, but this is returning an error:

`botocore.exceptions.ProxyConnectionError: Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://192.168.0.116:8080"`

This value is the IP address given by Docker Desktop as the `http_proxy` variable for the LocalStack container.

The relevant code (part of a larger function and class) using the boto3 package is:

```
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='test', aws_secret_access_key='test')
client = session.client('s3', endpoint_url='http://<name_of_container>:4566')
result = client.get_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=folder+'/'+file_name)
```

I have tried several values for the endpoint url, including the container name without the 'http://' and also without the port number. I have also tried the IP address given in the `docker network inspect` section for the LocalStack container, all without success (some give an 'invalid endpoint' error rather than the proxy connection error above).

The correctly-working first endpoint has the following code:

```
@app.route('/asset1')
def first_asset():
    # Defining the class object. The container name is used as the hostname when reading from Postgres
    pg_obj = pg_crud('test-db', <container_name>, 'postgres', 'password')
    test_json = pg_obj.read_json_from_pg_table_to_dict(<relevant function variables>)
    return jsonify(test_json)
```

So using the container name as the hostname here works correctly.
The second endpoint has the following code:

```
@app.route('/asset2')
def second_asset():
    # Defining the class object
    json_obj = s3_crud_json(<endpoint_url>, 'test-bucket')
    test_dict = json_obj.read_json_from_s3(<relevant function variables>)
    return jsonify(test_dict)
```

The fact that I can read from Postgres with psycopg2 successfully leads me to believe the bridge network is working correctly, and I just need to find the right configuration for boto3 to work properly.

Any idea what endpoint url should be used, or if something else could be wrong? Happy to provide more info if needed. Thanks!

Edit: The LocalStack container was created from one docker-compose file which looks as follows:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: cube-localstack
    ports:
      - '4563-4599:4563-4599'
      - '8055:8080'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,secretsmanager
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    volumes:
      - './.localstack:/tmp/localstack'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

The Flask app was created with the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
     api:
          build: ./api
          container_name: api_container
          ports:
               - '5000:5000'
          networks:
               - cube_net

networks:
     cube_net:
          external: true
```

The LocalStack container was added manually to the `cube_net` network using `docker network connect cube_net cube-localstack*`

Postgres was pulled from the official image and essentially run as it is.

*wrote the wrong container name here originally but did it correctly for the real thing

Edit 2: Added the 3 containers to one new docker-compose that looks like this:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: localstack_test
    ports:
      - '4563-4599:4563-4599'
      - '8055:8080'
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3,secretsmanager
      - DEBUG=1
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    volumes:
      - './.localstack:/tmp/localstack'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
  
  api:
    build: ./api
    container_name: api_test
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pg_test
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '5431:5432'
```

Flask app now looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index_page():
    return jsonify({'greeting': 'welcome to a simple Flask app', 'hello': 'world'})


@app.route('/asset1')
def first_asset():
    pg_obj = pg_crud('test-db', 'pg_test', 'postgres', 'password')
    test_json = pg_obj.read_json_from_pg_table_to_dict(<function variables>)
    return jsonify(test_json)


@app.route('/asset2')
def second_asset():
    json_obj = s3_crud_json(r'http://localstack_test:4566', 'test-bucket')
    test_dict = json_obj.read_json_from_s3(<function variables>)
    return jsonify(test_dict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

This now gives an invalid endpoint error for the following urls:

- http://localstack_test:4566 (as above)
- http://localstack_test
- localstack_test:4566
- localstack

The flask app DOES work when run locally and not in the container and using http://localhost:4566 as the endpoint url.

Comment: Could you also share your docker compose file?

Comment: Sure, just added them now!

Comment: You connect the `api_container` to the `cube_net` network using `docker network connect cube_net api_container`. But it should be `localstack`, right? Because `api_container` is already in `cube_net` network.

Comment: Oops that was a typo on here haha, all the containers are correctly on `cube_net` on the real thing

Comment: Try giving a specific name to your network in the second docker-compose file.
`name: cube_net`. Because I suspect that the network name is not just `cube_net` but it also adds the name of the directory your API service resides in.

Comment: Gave this a try but it doesn't seem to have worked. I think if the network name wasn't being correctly assigned as "cube_net" then the connection to the postgres container wouldn't have worked right? The fact connecting to one container works and not the other makes me think it could be more to do with the boto3 module and how it interacts with LocalStack

Comment: Okay, then as a trial, you can try to add all the services in one docker compose file. Remove all network configurations in the compose file (this will make them default). Then `api` service should be able to call `localstack` service just by using `http://localstack:<PORT>`. If this works, we can rule out that the issue is coming from your boto3 module.

Comment: OR you can run the `localstack` compose file as it is. But run `api` in your local machine without using Docker. Since you have exported the ports, using `http://localhost:<PORT>`, `api` should be able to access your `localstack`.
BTW, can you also put your docker compose file for Postgres?

Comment: Just added that extra info - tried adding all three to a single docker-compose. It isn't giving a proxy error anymore which is good, but I'm not sure what endpoint-url or hostname it wants. Tried a few things which you can see in the edit above. Thanks for the advice so far!

Comment: You're almost there. Let's hope the S3 service in localstack is listening from port 4566. Then you need to set `s3_crud_json('http://localstack:4566', 'test-bucket')`. Here, `localstack` is the name of the service in docker compose file as well as the hostname of the service. But you still need to give a port which is 4566 because that service internally have multiple other services like SQS, S3 etc. Hence port 4566. :-)

Comment: Ah I was thinking I needed to use the container name as the hostname! This seems very close however it is now giving `botocore.exceptions.ProxyConnectionError: Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://192.168.0.116:8080"` again :(

Comment: Try using `s3_crud_json('localstack:4566', 'test-bucket')`. (Remove `http` part)

Comment: `localstack:4566` gives an invalid endpoint error again

Comment: Okay, I'm out of ideas now. 

Comment: Haha me too... thank you for your suggestions anyway! Hopefully I'll figure it out by chance

Comment: Did you ever solve this?
I'm currently struggling getting a .NET Lambda (running in localstack) to communicate with an S3 bucket (also running in localstack)

Comment: In the end I got it to work by removing every reference to a proxy URL in any location, so in the dockerfile, docker-compose, and localstack config, and maybe in environment variables too I can't quite remember. It seemed like localstack was just very determined to use a proxy URL so was trying to find one wherever it could. Hope this works for you!